# как обновить страницу при вызове функции

Tags: reactjs

у меня есть функция fetchdata, которая записывает в localstorage обьект данных по запросу из инпута, как мне обновлять страницу /coin при повторном вызове функции fetchdata, вот код:

```
const fetchData = (coin) => {

  return fetch(`${API_URL_SEARCH}/${coin}`)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
        localStorage.setItem('coinObject', JSON.stringify(data));
        return data;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error.message);
    });
};

export const ShowSearch = () => {
  const [coin, setCoin] = useState('');

  const handleCoin = (event) => {
    setCoin(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    fetchData(coin);
    ShowCoinInfo(coin);
  };

  return (
    <div>
        <input
          type='text'
          placeholder='Выберите монету'
          onChange={handleCoin}
          className="search-input"
        />
        <Link to='/coin'>
          <button onClick={handleSubmit} className="search-button">Найти</button>
        </Link>
    </div>
  );
};
```

попытался решить таким способом:

```
  const handleSubmit = () => {
    fetchData(coin);
    window.location.reload();
    ShowCoinInfo(coin);
  };
```

но теперь при запросе, он показывает данные, потом обновляет страницу и скидывает ссылку

Comment: Реакт обновлять, вызывая `window.location.reload()`, неправильно. Реакт должен отрисовываться в зависимости от стейта. Т.е. для перерисовки страницы тебе нужно "обновить" стейт. Не менять, а просто обновить ссылки на массивы, объекты...

Comment: @ksa благодарю, вы помогли мне